# Mysql answers from mulitple rows (questions) into one row per child

Tags: mysql

I have a table that records answers to questions that are answered multiple times per year.
The table has a columns for the user **ID**, the year they took the question, the  month they took the question, the subject and the question number

```
ID  | Year | Month | Subject | Q number| Answer |
-------------------------------------------------
1   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 2       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 3       | no     |
1   | 2016 | 01    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 01    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 01    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  01     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  01     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  01     | 2       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  01     | 3       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
1   | 2016 | 02    |  02     | 1       | Yes    |
2   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 1       | Yes    |
2   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 2       | no     |
2   | 2016 | 01    |  01     | 3       | no     |etc
```

I want to create a query that returns **one row per user** with a column for each answer.

```
ID | 2016-01_sub01_Q01 | 2016-01_sub01_Q02 | 2016-01_sub01_Q03 | etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | yes               | yes               | no                |  etc  
2  | yes               | no                | no                |  etc
```

I've tried multiple **left joins** onto the results table matching for each answer but the query is still running and thats just with 2 subjects (out of 13+) and 9 qs per subject.

```
select u.userid, 
    Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.answer,
    Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q2.answer,
    Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q3.answer,

from users u 
left join answers Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1 on ( 
            answers.userid = users.userid 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.year = 2016 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.mon = 02 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.sub = 01 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.question = 1) 
left join answers Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q2 on ( 
            answers.userid = users.userid 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.year = 2016 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.mon = 02 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.sub = 01 
            and Y2016_Mon2_Sub01_Q1.question = 2) 
etc
```

But as you can imagine that's becoming an issue to manage and with all subjects and questions I'd end up with 100's joins.  I've tried searching multiple results to one row but not found anything yet...  Any clues/ examples appreciated.  I keep finding **group_concat** but I need the answers in their own columns.

Comment: You better do that in php maybe

Comment: yeah, when I rewrite the query to get the data to then do the "One line per user in php" the query takes <1 sec.   But I've had this type of challenge several times before and always thought... "can I do this just in sql?" but never got round to asking

Comment: Try this if I understood your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: that's not quite it as it sums / counts the number of occurrences.  I just want to get all of each users answers on one row, with a column per question

Comment: The PHP solution is simpler and more easily scalable.